# How to update data in RecylerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a recyclerview adapter in which each view has a button. I want to implement a fuc=nctionality such that if I click button on any view all the views of the recyclerview should be updated. How this can be achieved ?
This is what I have done in onBindViewHolder

```
 public class StoryItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StoryItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
Bitmap bm;
ImageLoader imloader;
static ArrayList<StoryDetails> stories;


OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
public StoryItemAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<StoryDetails> stories) {
    this.context = context;
    this.stories = stories;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imloader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));


}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return stories != null ? stories.size() : 0;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    if(stories.get(position).getType()==null) {
        holder.user_handle.setText(stories.get(position).getUsername() + "( " + stories.get(position).getHandle() + " )");

        File file = imloader.getDiscCache().get(stories.get(position).getImage());
        if (!file.exists()) {
            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .cacheOnDisc()
                    .build();
            imloader.displayImage(stories.get(position).getImage(), holder.image, options);
        } else {
            holder.image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }

        holder.about.setText(stories.get(position).getAbout());
        holder.followers.setText("Followers\n\r" + stories.get(position).getFollowers());
        holder.following.setText("Following\n\r" + stories.get(position).getFollowing());
    }
    else
    {
        holder.user_handle.setText(stories.get(position).getTitle());

        File file = imloader.getDiscCache().get(stories.get(position).getSi());
        if (!file.exists()) {
            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .cacheOnDisc()
                    .build();
            imloader.displayImage(stories.get(position).getSi(), holder.image, options);
        } else {
            holder.image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }

        holder.about.setText(stories.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.followers.setText("Likes \n\r" + stories.get(position).getLikes_count());
        holder.following.setText("Comments \n\r" + stories.get(position).getComment_count());


    }

    if(stories.get(position).getIs_following())
    {
        holder.follow.setText("Following");
    }
    else
        holder.follow.setText("Follow");

    final int  p = position;
    final ViewHolder h = holder;

    holder.follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(stories.get(p).getIs_following())
            {
                stories.get(p).setIs_following(false);
                h.follow.setText("Follow");


            }
            else {
                stories.get(p).setIs_following(true);
                h.follow.setText("Following");
            }


            for(int i =0;i <stories.size();i++) {
                if (stories.get(p).getDb() != null) {

                    if(stories.get(p).getDb().equals(stories.get(i).getId()))
                    {
                        stories.get(p).setIs_following(stories.get(i).getIs_following());

                    }


                }
            }



        }
    });


}



@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.story_adapter, viewGroup,
            false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);

}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView image;
    TextView user_handle, about, followers,following,userSince;
    Button follow;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        user_handle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_handle);
        about = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.about);
        followers = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.followers);
        following = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.following);
       // userSince = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_since);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_image);
        follow =(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.follow);



        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        image.setLayoutParams(rlp);
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        if (mItemClickListener != null) {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
        }
    }

}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view , int position);
}

public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}
```

}

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar updated

Comment: I think you need : RecyclerView.getChildAt(int index).....More Hint => From OnClick you can call another method updateMyViews() and inside this loop through all the index values(upto arraylist size), obtain view using above function and update them. Later if needed call notifyDataSetChange() on adapter

Comment: The following statement may be meant the other way round: not `stories.get(p).setIs_following(stories.get(i).getIs_following());` but `stories.get(i).setIs_following(stories.get(p).getIs_following());`  ? Else it makes no sense to previously set the "following/ follow" value for stories.get(p)

Comment: as 0X0nosugar pointed out => there is small bug in your code. Inside for loop stories.get(p) must be stories.get(i)

Comment: Another logic failure I notice is, why you even need a for loop, OnClick is going to change only one item value(is_Following) of Stories_list single item, then you need to update only 1 value in db, why update for every item of stories_list  ??

Comment: If only single item is changed => notifyItemChanged(index) of recycler view will do the job.

Comment: @kishorepatel I need to update all the views whose id == db . That's the task :)

Comment: ok, then you shoud notify complete dataset

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the Adapter about any dataset changed.

Try this..

```
 holder.follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(stories.get(p).getIs_following())
            {
                stories.get(p).setIs_following(false);
                h.follow.setText("Follow");


            }
            else {
                stories.get(p).setIs_following(true);
                h.follow.setText("Following");
            }


            for(int i =0;i <stories.size();i++) {
                if (stories.get(p).getDb() != null) {

                    if(stories.get(p).getDb().equals(stories.get(i).getId()))
                    {
                        stories.get(p).setIs_following(stories.get(i).getIs_following());

                    }


                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Comment: one approach would be tag the value in each textViewObject in on click and then call, notifyDataSetChanged(), this will again call OnBindViewHolder() callback, there you can get the tag for that textView and set it against it.